# Using case class for json validation and MongoDB persistense (Reactivemongo), what about id?

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework-2.0, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

So, I have a case class as well as readers and writers for both JSON and BSONDocument format.

Problem is, when inserting to MongoDB, I want to be able to specify the BSONObjectID, so I can return it upon creation. However, if I add a `id: BSONObjectID` in the case class, I cannot find a way to get the JSON validation/transformation to work.

This is my code:

```
case class Mini(username: String, email: String, quizAnswer1: List[String] )

implicit object MiniWriter extends BSONDocumentWriter[Mini] {
  def write(mini: Mini): BSONDocument = BSONDocument(
    "username" -> mini.username,
    "email" -> mini.email,
    "quizAnswer1" -> mini.quizAnswer1
  )
}

implicit object MiniReader extends BSONDocumentReader[Mini] {
  def read(doc: BSONDocument): Mini = Mini(
    doc.getAs[String]("username").get,
    doc.getAs[String]("email").get,
    doc.getAs[List[String]]("quizAnswer1").toList.flatten
  )
}

implicit val miniReads: Reads[Mini] = (
  (JsPath \ "username").read[String] and
  (JsPath \ "email").read[String] and
  (JsPath \ "quizAnswer1").read[List[String]]
)(Mini.apply _)

implicit val miniWrites: Writes[Mini] = (
  (JsPath \ "username").write[String] and
  (JsPath \ "email").write[String] and
  (JsPath \ "quizAnswer1").write[List[String]]
)(unlift(Mini.unapply))
```

I really want to avoid working with duplicate model representations of the same model. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the id in the model itself you could just use it temporarly while your operations. On a PUT you could use a following base implementation:

```
def insert(t: T)(implicit ctx: ExecutionContext): Future[BSONObjectID] = {
    val id = BSONObjectID.generate
    val obj = format.writes(t).as[JsObject]
    obj \ "_id" match {
      case _: JsUndefined =>
        coll.insert(obj ++ Json.obj("_id" -> id)).map { _ => id }

     case JsObject(Seq((_, JsString(oid)))) =>
        coll.insert(obj).map { _ => BSONObjectID(oid) }

     case JsString(oid) =>
        coll.insert(obj).map { _ => BSONObjectID(oid) }

     case f => sys.error(s"Could not parse _id field: $f")
}
```

}

On an update the id is provided by the POST request.

When you query the db you could use the following base implementation to get the ids of the resultset temporary

```
def find(sel: JsObject, limit: Int = 0, skip: Int = 0, sort: JsObject = Json.obj(), projection: JsObject = Json.obj())(implicit ctx: ExecutionContext): Future[Traversable[(T, BSONObjectID)]] = {
    val cursor = coll.find(sel).projection(projection).sort(sort).options(QueryOpts().skip(skip).batchSize(limit)).cursor[JsObject]
    val l = if (limit != 0) cursor.collect[Traversable](limit) else cursor.collect[Traversable]()
    l.map(_.map(js => (js.as[T], (js \ "_id").as[BSONObjectID])))
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that answer took me in the right direction. I did also put in Option's into the final solution for other fields that aren't mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Using play you could use play's json fomrat/read/write directly:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonCombinators

An example would look like:

```
object Mini {
    implicit val miniFormat: Format[Mini] = Json.format[Mini]
}
```

As far as I know you have to declare the id object with '_id'.

```
case class Mini(_id:BSONObjectId, username: String, email: String, quizAnswer1: List[String] )
```

For the implicit convertion of the BSONObjectId you can use the following format:

```
implicit object BSONObjectIDFormat extends Format[BSONObjectID] {
def writes(objectId: BSONObjectID): JsValue = {
  Json.obj("$oid" -> JsString(objectId.stringify))
}
def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[BSONObjectID] = json match {
  case JsString(x) => {
    val maybeOID: Try[BSONObjectID] = BSONObjectID.parse(x)
    if (maybeOID.isSuccess) JsSuccess(maybeOID.get) else {
      JsError("Expected BSONObjectID as JsString")
    }
  }

  case JsObject(Seq((_, oid))) =>
    reads(oid)

  case _ => JsError("Expected BSONObjectID as JsString")
}
```

}

Comment: I think I'm ending up with using two case classes, one with the _id for internal use, adding the _id upon creation, the other one to expose to the API. Reason is that when doing a PUT (create) or POST (update), the _id shouldn't be given. In a PUT it is created and returned. In a POST the _id comes from the URL path, like '/mini/a675c76d576d5c'. So, I add the generated BSONObjectID to the json structure and validate it with the internal case class and its writes, then I do the final conversion on the internal version of the case class with _id using BSONDocument writer.

Comment: If you don't need the id in the model itself you could just use it temporarly while your operations. On a PUT you could use a following base implementation: